# How do I save input inside a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitextview, swiftyuserdefaults

How do I save input in a UITextView once my application is double tapped out/force quitted? Is there some code I can write on the `textViewDidChange` call that can automatically save the input?
NOTE: The last code section is where the UITextView is located.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var obj : observed
    @ObservedObject var date1 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date2 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date3 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date4 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date5 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date6 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date7 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date8 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date9 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var date10 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var reason1 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject var reason2 = SaveSettings()
    @ObservedObject private var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            ScrollView(.vertical) {
                VStack {
                    HStack {
                        Text("My Journey").font(.largeTitle).foregroundColor(.blue).bold()   }
                    // Entry 1
                    HStack {
                        Text("Date: ").foregroundColor(.blue).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        TextField("Month/Day/Year", text: $date1.date)
                            .padding(.bottom, 8.0)
                            .frame(width: 170.0)
                            .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.leading)
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            DropDown()
                        }
                        
                        HStack {
                            Text("What's going on?")
                                .font(.headline)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                                .padding(.all, 8.0)
                            Spacer()
                            Button("Done") {
                                self.hideKeyboard()
                            }
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            MultiTextField().frame(height : self.obj.size < 150 ? self.obj.size : 150).padding(10).background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(10)
                        }.padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 33, trailing: 25))
                        
                        
                        // Entry 2
                        HStack {
                            Text("Date: ").foregroundColor(.blue).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing).padding([.top, .leading])
                            TextField("Month/Day/Year", text: $date2.date2)
                                .padding(.vertical, 8.0)
                                .frame(width: 170.0)
                                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                            Spacer()
                            
                        }
                        VStack {
                            HStack {
                                DropDown2()
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text("What's going on?")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                                    .padding(.all, 8.0)
                                Spacer()
                                Button("Done") {
                                    self.hideKeyboard()
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                MultiTextField().frame(height : self.obj.size < 150 ? self.obj.size : 150).padding(10).background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 33, trailing: 25))
                            
                            // Entry 3
                            HStack {
                                Text("Date:").foregroundColor(.blue)
                                    .bold().padding(.leading)
                                TextField("Month/Day/Year", text: $date3.date3)
                                    .frame(width: 170.0)
                                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                                Spacer()
                                
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                DropDown3()
                                
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                Text("What's going on?")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                                    .padding(.all, 8.0)
                                Spacer()
                                Button("Done") {
                                    self.hideKeyboard()
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            
                            HStack {
                                MultiTextField().frame(height : self.obj.size < 150 ? self.obj.size : 150).padding(10).background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(10)
                            }
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 33, trailing: 25))
                            
                            Group {
                                
                                // Entry 4
                                HStack {
                                    Text("Date: ").foregroundColor(.blue).fontWeight(.bold).multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                                    TextField("Month/Day/Year", text: $date4.date4)
                                        .padding(.bottom, 8.0)
                                        .frame(width: 170.0)
                                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                                    Spacer()
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(.leading)
                                
                                VStack {
                                    HStack {
                                        DropDown4()
                                    }
                                }
                                
                                HStack {
                                    Text("What's going on?")
                                        .font(.headline)
                                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                                        .foregroundColor(Color.purple)
                                        .padding(.all, 8.0)
                                    Spacer()
                                    Button("Done") {
                                        self.hideKeyboard()
                                    }
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                                
                                HStack {
                                    MultiTextField().frame(height : self.obj.size < 150 ? self.obj.size : 150).padding(10).background(Color.gray).cornerRadius(10)
                                }
                                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 25, bottom: 33, trailing: 25))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.padding(.bottom, keyboard.currentHeight)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

---

```
struct DropDown: View {
    @State var expand = false
    @ObservedObject var feeling = SaveSettings()
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                HStack() {
                    Text("I am feeling: ").bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(feeling.feeling).bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 13, height:6)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.expand.toggle()
                }
                if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Happy"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Happy")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Frustrated"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Frustrated")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Disappointed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Disappointed")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Excited"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Excited")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Amused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Amused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Anxious"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Anxious")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Confused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Confused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Admiration"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Admiration")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling.feeling = "Embarassed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Embarrased")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling.feeling = "Nostalgic"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Nostalgic")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling.feeling = "Surprised"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Surprised")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).cornerRadius(15).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5).animation(.interactiveSpring()) 
    }
}
```

---

```
struct DropDown2: View {
    
    @State var expand = false
    @ObservedObject var feeling2 = SaveSettings()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                HStack() {
                    Text("I am feeling: ").bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(feeling2.feeling2).bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 13, height:6)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.expand.toggle()
                }
                if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Happy"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Happy")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Frustrated"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("Frustrated")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Disappointed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Disappointed")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Excited"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Excited")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Amused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Amused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Anxious"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Anxious")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Confused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Confused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Admiration"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Admiration")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Embarassed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Embarrased")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Nostalgic"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Nostalgic")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling2.feeling2 = "Surprised"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Surprised")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).cornerRadius(15).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5).animation(.interactiveSpring())  
    }
}
```

---

```
struct DropDown3: View {
    @State var expand = false
    @ObservedObject var feeling3 = SaveSettings()
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                HStack() {
                    Text("I am feeling: ").bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(feeling3.feeling3).bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 13, height:6)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.expand.toggle()
                }
                if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Happy"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Happy")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Frustrated"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("Frustrated")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Disappointed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Disappointed")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Excited"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Excited")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Amused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Amused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Anxious"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Anxious")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Confused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Confused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling = "Admiration"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Admiration")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Embarassed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Embarrased")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Nostalgic"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Nostalgic")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling3.feeling3 = "Surprised"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Surprised")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).cornerRadius(15).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5).animation(.interactiveSpring())  
    }
}
```

---

```
struct DropDown4: View {
    @State var expand = false
    @ObservedObject var feeling4 = SaveSettings()
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                HStack() {
                    Text("I am feeling: ").bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text(feeling4.feeling4).bold().foregroundColor(.white)
                    Image(systemName: expand ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down").resizable().frame(width: 13, height:6)
                }.onTapGesture {
                    self.expand.toggle()
                }
                if expand {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Happy"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Happy")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Frustrated"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        
                        Text("Frustrated")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Disappointed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Disappointed")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Excited"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Excited")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Amused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Amused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Anxious"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Anxious")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Confused"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Confused")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Admiration"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Admiration")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Embarassed"
                        self.expand.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Embarrased")
                    }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                    Group {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Nostalgic"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Nostalgic")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                        
                        Button(action: {
                            self.feeling4.feeling4 = "Surprised"
                            self.expand.toggle()
                        }) {
                            Text("Surprised")
                        }.foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }.padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: .init(colors: [.blue, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).cornerRadius(15).shadow(color: .gray, radius: 5).animation(.interactiveSpring())   
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MultiTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return MultiTextField.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }    
    @EnvironmentObject var obj : observed
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiTextField>) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        view.text = " "
        view.textColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.350)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        self.obj.size = view.contentSize.height
        view.isEditable = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.isSelectable = true
        return view
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MultiTextField>) {
    }
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent : MultiTextField
        init(parent1 : MultiTextField) {
            parent = parent1
        }
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.textColor = .black
        }
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.obj.size = textView.contentSize.height
            UserDefaults.standard.set(textView.text, forKey: "TextViewTextToRestore") //added
        }
        func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            print("Editing is done")
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. The ideal way:

You may need to play with `UIViewController`'s state restoration. Please try https://www.raywenderlich.com/1395-state-restoration-tutorial-getting-started.

#### 2. Quick Solution:

Whenever there a change in text field value in `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`, try to save the value in `UserDefaults`. [NON-SENSITIVE DATA ONLY]

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    self.parent.obj.size = textView.contentSize.height
    // Save field value in Defaults
    UserDefaults.standard.set(textView.text, forKey: "TextViewTextToRestore")
    UserDefaults.standard..synchronize()
}
```

Now you can restore the value in `viewDidLoad()`.

```
override func viewDidload() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   if txtFileText = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TextViewTextToRestore") {
      textView.text = txtFileText
   }
}
```

**CAUTION:** DO NOT FORGET TO CLEAR THE VALUE FROM DEFAULTS IF USER EXITS THE SCREEN NORMALLY OR ACCORDING TO YOUR USE-CASE.

Comment: Thia assumes the textview content is plain text

Comment: Where should I put the override function? I am currently placing it below the textViewDidChange but it's throwing errors. Thanks @LeoDabus

Comment: In your view controller subclass where you might have declared an `IBOutlet` for the discussed `UITextView`.

Comment: @SauvikDolui this question is tagged as SwiftUI

Comment: @LeoDabus also, the link you provided I tried, but it seems that some of the directions are only applicable to story board not swiftui. are there some other commands in the website that have changed?

Comment: @sid_bakshy the equivalent to viewDidLoad in SwiftUI for your `View` would be `.onAppear { // your code }`

Comment: func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.obj.size = textView.contentSize.height
            
        }.onAppear() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if txtFileText = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "TextViewToRestore") {
        textView.text = txtFileText
        }
        }

Comment: this is my code, but there are erros coming up saying "expected declaration". So sorry if this is buggy, just not sure what to do @LeoDabus

Comment: @sid_bakshy edit your question and add the complete class (or struct) where your updateUIView method is located.

Comment: Can you edit your post and format it properly. Tip: before copy/pasting your code here just indent it (select all lines you want and press command-] in your keyboard) it will move your code 4 spaces to the right in Xcode. Now copy and paste it here. It will become automatically formatted.

Comment: @LeoDabus All of the code from the class is reforatted.

Comment: @sid_bakshy Are you sure `class Coordinator` is declared inside your `struct MultiTextField`?

Comment: Yes it is, i just checked @LeoDabus